# translating a C for loop to Pascal

Tags: c, pascal

I am translating an "old" C program into (Object) Pascal.
I am reconsidering my translation of the following:

```
for (objlist = list->unbounded; objlist; objlist = objlist->next) {
  /* do stuff */
}
```

At first I translated the loop as follows:

```
objlist := list.unbounded;
repeat
  // do stuff
  objlist := objlist.next;
until objlist = nil;
```

But then I wondered, what happens if "objList" is nil?
Should the loop be translated as a while loop (so objList can be tested before entering the loop)?

```
objlist := list.unbounded;
while (objlist <> nil) do
  begin
    // do stuff
    objlist := objlist.next;
  end;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only issue I see here is you made a correct analysis, made the appropriate change, but then doubted yourself.

Comment: Is Pascal still used? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a while loop for sure. C for-loop is actually a while-loop

Answer (score 0):

You should always strive to writing robust code, code which works even when the premises changes and a pointer suddenly could become null. It is good practice to check a pointer for null before using it.

Even thou it looks like the c code is a `repeat`... `until` The c for loop actually checks for null on the first iteration.

You could try this with a simple example

```
#include <stdio.h>
  
int main(){
  for(int i=20 ;i < 10;i++){
      printf("%d\n",i);
   }
   return 0;

}
```

*see this flow diagram [image: C loop for diagram] from*  https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-for-loop/

And even if the original code did not check for an initial null pointer I would recommend the second while loop style.